# oracle calling sp with ref_cursor out in toad

Tags: oracle, toad

Where does it go wrong, please?

spec:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE CTI_MATRIX.AMD AS
  TYPE REF_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
  PROCEDURE AMD_NEEDMSG (v_CRN IN VARCHAR2, return_recordset OUT REF_CURSOR);
END AMD;
```

body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CTI_MATRIX.AMD AS
PROCEDURE AMD_NEEDMSG (v_CRN IN VARCHAR2, return_recordset OUT REF_CURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
    -- 
END AMD_NEEDMSG;
END AMD;
```

Failing block from TOAD:

```
DECLARE 
RETURN_RECORDSET AMD.REF_CURSOR;
BEGIN 
    RETURN_RECORDSET := NULL;
    CTI_MATRIX.AMD.AMD_NEEDMSG ( '123456789', RETURN_RECORDSET );
END;
```

Error: PLS-00382 Expression is of wrong type line 5

Comment: weird, perdon my silly question but did you compile everything last time (SPECS especially) ?

Comment: More examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305883/toad-displaying-cursor-recordset-returned-by-stored-procedure/14320426#14320426

Answer (score 0):

who are you logged on as?

as:

```
DECLARE 
RETURN_RECORDSET AMD.REF_CURSOR;
BEGIN 
    RETURN_RECORDSET := NULL;
    CTI_MATRIX.AMD.AMD_NEEDMSG ( '123456789', RETURN_RECORDSET );
END;
```

is correct syntax, but i see you are prefixing the owner on the package call (CTI_MATRIX) but NOT on the declaration of `RETURN_RECORDSET AMD.REF_CURSOR;`. if you're calling this as another user that also has a copy of the package `AMD` then you'd get this error message.

Also no need to assign `NULL` to the recordset on line 4.

Comment: Tried with:

`DECLARE 
RETURN_RECORDSET CTI_MATRIX.AMD.REF_CURSOR;
BEGIN 
    CTI_MATRIX.AMD.AMD_NEEDMSG ( '123456789', RETURN_RECORDSET );
END;`

but still getting:

ORA-20001: An error was encountered ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
ORA-06512: at "CTI_MATRIX.AMD", line 69
ORA-06512: at line 4

Then after adding ':' to RETURN_RECORDSET in
`CTI_MATRIX.AMD.AMD_NEEDMSG ( '123456789', :RETURN_RECORDSET );`

produced error message:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'AMD_NEEDMSG'
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: @user1970875 `ORA-06512: at "CTI_MATRIX.AMD", line 69 ` = a code fault in your API itself on line 69 so you need to fix that before anything else. and why did you put a colon on `:RETURN_RECORDSET` ? this is only used for bind variables, not plsql variables.

Answer (score 0):

In the procedure the second parameter is of type "REF_CURSOR", while in the testing pl/sql block it is "AMD.REF_CURSOR". Check if the two types are the same, i guess they aren't. Or change the testing pl/sql block so that you define the variable like this:

```
RETURN_RECORDSET CTI_MATRIX.AMD.REF_CURSOR;
```

Comment: Tried with: DECLARE RETURN_RECORDSET CTI_MATRIX.AMD.REF_CURSOR; BEGIN CTI_MATRIX.AMD.AMD_NEEDMSG ( '123456789', RETURN_RECORDSET ); END; but still getting: ORA-20001: An error was encountered ORA-00937: not a single-group group function ORA-06512: at "CTI_MATRIX.AMD", line 69 ORA-06512: at line 4 Then after adding ':' to RETURN_RECORDSET in CTI_MATRIX.AMD.AMD_NEEDMSG ( '123456789', :RETURN_RECORDSET ); produced error message: ORA-06550: line 4, column 3: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'AMD_NEEDMSG' ORA-06550: line 4, column 3: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: First fix the error in the package CTI_MATRIX.AMD, line 69. Something is wrong with the select statement at that line, it has to do with group by. Then try to execute your block again.